# Schedule reminder send also to the staff

Tags: scheduled-reminders

Currently, our members receive a reminder one day before their membership is about to expire.
We'd like that inside the team 2 persons receive as well this reminders so we can reply to this automatic message and follow it by something more personal to the member category.

Is this possible using CiviCRM? We use Wordpress.
Thank you in advance for all the help!

Comment: Please could you add some detail of what you have tried and what documentation you have looked at but didn't provide the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at using the "Also include" option: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/#limiting-or-adding-to-your-recipient-list

"If you want to send a scheduled reminder to contact(s) who do not meet the general criteria for that reminder you should set **Limit or Add Recipients** to **Also include.** You can then select a group of contacts or an individual who will receive the reminder even if they don't meet the other criteria."

So you can then put your 2 staff members in a group or manually add both.

[image]